# Did J. Michael Straczynski (JMS) always plan for these scenes to happen as they did in B5?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, babylon-5

In season one of B5 Londo has his visions, he sees a number of events happen one of which is he and G'Kar killing each other.

In Season 3 we see the G'kar Death scene more fully as Delenn and Sheridan travel forward through time. Londo has a parasite attached to him and drinks to make it sleep and gets a one eyed G'kar to kill him in order to save Sheridan and Delenn as they escape.

Was this how JMS planned it all from the start (Season 1) or did he later flesh out the story to make this premonition come true?

Comment: Ray, when someone asks you if JMS planned it from the start, you say YES.

Comment: @gowenfawr Except for ending it at the end of season 4 and then **not** ending it and adding season 5.

Comment: @ToddWilcox he *planned* everything from the start.  Being able to salvage anything from the godawful mess that was the implosion of the PTEN network was improvisation, and if it wasn't as good as the rest of it, at least it was something.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Events in Season 5 were intended from the beginning, they were just supposed to be sprinkled among the main plot that got squashed into Season 4 (which itself was supposed to span both seasons).

Comment: @Izkata Yeah, I **know** all that, I guess my comment was badly worded. It was originally planned for 5 seasons. Then he had to shorten it to 4, then he was able to add the stuff he took out back in for a 5th season. That's all I was saying. It's like people are commenting, "Todd what you said was wrong, what actually happened is exactly what you said".

Comment: @gowenfawr If you insist, but I really think you're overestimating how likely people are to consult me on this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Signs point to yes.**

Creator JMS replied on Usenet and mentioned this regarding the first time this particular portion of the vision is shown (Londo talks about it earlier, but the audience first sees it in Season 2, *Coming of Shadows*).  Quote lifted from the archive at the [Lurker's Guide](http://midwinter.com/lurk/countries/us/guide/031.html):

> I ended up giving Peter info on "Signs" prior to shooting "Chrysalis" last season; that was the biggie there. For "CoS" in order for the scene to match what's going to happen several years down the road in the series, I had to kinda give him the context of the dream, and what was really happening in that scene, and what caused it, and how he got to that place with G'Kar's hands around his throat.
>   He seemed quite...astonished.

A later comment regarding the payoff from [*War Without End*](http://midwinter.com/lurk/countries/us/guide/061.html):

> I seem to recall, after that Londo/G'Kar scene was shown the last time, posting somewhere that folks now knew *what* has happened, but they don't yet know the *context*. Very few picked up on that and thought to actually reverse what they *thought* they were seeing to what they *might* be seeing.

Comment: Should that be “Signs & Portents point to yes”? ;-)

Comment: @Thunderforge Not enough caffeine or alcohol in my system this early to enjoy any pun, let alone the bad ones. >_<

Comment: I loved this about B5. JMS regularly came on to the Usenet forum and answered questions. From time to time he would tell fans things like *pay attention to this scene in this week's episode - it will be important down the road*

Comment: @Radhil But that's a good pun.